# (Django) How to make an image display from my computer instead of being searched on localhost?

Tags: html, django

I've been tearing my hair out on this... I can't get any images displayed on my website. I tried using absolute paths, relative paths, I tried different folders, but nothing seems to work...
Here is the html code:

```
<img src="download.jpg"  width="300" height="230" style="display: block;">
```

It is obviously in the same folder and the file name is correct. But here is what the django server is showing me:

```
[03/Jan/2015 09:43:15] "GET /index/download.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2865
```

So it seems that it's trying to look for the image on the website (/index is my current location). How do I make it look for the image on my computer? I tried doing C:/{full path} but that didn't work...

Thanks!

Comment: You should not load from C:/... It is loading from your computer thru the django development server. Based on the url, it seems you have invalid MEDIA_URL. Can you show you settings.py MEDIA_URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you dont put paths in django like in php. django (if running locally, otherwise httpserver) serves them from static folder whose settings you need to make in settings.py

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

and in your template load on the top only once:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

and then in template

```
<img src="{% static "img/download.jpg" %}" alt="My image"/>
```

provided, you have

```
-static
---img
---css
---js
```

folder as usual

[**read more**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/)